# Utility to normalize text files

Tags: command-line, textfiles

Does there exist a command line utility to check for and ideally fix grunge in text files? e.g.

- Inconsistent or non-native line endings (lf vs cr/lf)
- Extra whitespace at end of lines
- Spurious byte order markings (Visual Studio sometimes inserts these, even though they are neither necessary nor desirable in UTF-8 files)

And possibly other things I hadn't thought of? (Closest I can find so far is something called tab2space, but the primary function of that is as it says on the tin, to expand tabs, and that's something I don't want.)

Comment: which OS shall it be?

Comment: Windows or Linux. (Though I would normally expect a utility like that, that doesn't need to do any platform specific stuff, to be cross-platform or at least easily portable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert to/from various line endings there are programs called `unix2dos`/`dos2unix` or `todos`/`fromdos`.

To remove extra whitespace at the end of the line you can use `sed s/[ \t]*$//` (do this step after correcting line endings).